# How to use Json library in web application

Tags: java, json, web-applications

I am working on a web application in JAVA, and I used org.json. in the project for some computation, but I get the following error message when I run the application from localhost.

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
```

I specified the dependency in pom.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org      /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.cloudera.oryx</groupId>
   <artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
   <version>0.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>

   <dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

EDITED: Full Pom.xml content

What other thing should be done to get this to running? Thanks.

Comment: That should be sufficient .... if you use "war" as the packaging.  But maybe there is some other problem in your POM file.  (Hint: post the entire file.)

Comment: Where the dependency is added ? `<dependencyManagement>` section or `<dependencies>` section ? Is that module based application ?

Comment: That's the parent pom (how I know: packaging type is pom). The real truth is in the pom of your web module so post -that-.

Comment: Where did I specify that, then? I had no idea about that, as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

There may be various reasons, you get `NoClassDefFoundError` even after adding the `dependency`

The following are the checks you can do to get.

- Add the dependency in `<dependencies>` section of your main pom.xml. If you feel like I dont require JSON library in service layer in an application like `Rest --> service --> DAO`, then add in `<dependencyManagement>` section and add the dependency with out version - in which ever module you want.
- You need to make sure that your `settings.xml` is configured right enough to get the jar files downloaded for you.
- Another possibility is `refresh` your workspace if you are using some IDE - eclipse, IntelliJ to get the dependencies updated.
- You can check `.m2 --> repository --> org --> json --> <version>` folder is available or not. This confirms that the jar is downloaded and you can tick point 2 as confirmed.
- You can unarchive the war file and check in the libraries whether the json jar file is added to your end packaging or not. This is the final place to check.
- You can use `mvn -U clean install` to update the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your POM's "packaging"

The normal way to build a webapp is to specify the packaging as "war" so that Maven will build a WAR file containing your code and the dependent JARs.  You then deploy the WAR file to the web container.

But you are using packaging "pom".

1. I'm assuming that means you've got another (child) POM file to build your application JAR.
2. I'm also guessing that you are using "jar" as the packaging in that POM.
3. I'm also assuming that you are then deploying the JAR to web container; e.g. by hand or using some IDE integration thingy.

I think that the problem here is that while you are deploying your JAR file to the web container, and you don't need to deploy the Jersey dependencies ('cos they are already there!!), you are NOT deploying the "json.org" JAR file.

At any rate, the reason that you are getting the exception is that the web container classloader cannot find that JAR file.  If you are deploying without using a WAR, *something* has to copy the file to the place where the web container's classloader is going to look.